# Struggle calling HTML classes in a Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, weather

I'm attempting to build a Weather website for school. I've finished the homepage to accurately display weather information based on the users current location. I am now attempting to make a forecast for the next 5 days. I can succesfully build this but the code is long because I'm not making use of a loop. But when attempting to build a loop I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Boston, MA',
    unit: 'c',
    success: function (weather) {
      /*day1 = weather.forecast[1].day;
      image1 = '<img class="weathericon" src="img/weathericons/' + weather.forecast[1].code + '.svg" alt="weather icon">';
      temp1 = weather.forecast[1].high + '&deg;';
      text1 = weather.forecast[1].text;

      day2 = weather.forecast[2].day;
      image2 = '<img class="weathericon" src="img/weathericons/' + weather.forecast[2].code + '.svg" alt="weather icon">';
      temp2 = weather.forecast[2].high + '&deg;';
      text2 = weather.forecast[2].text;

      day3 = weather.forecast[3].day;
      image3 = '<img class="weathericon" src="img/weathericons/' + weather.forecast[3].code + '.svg" alt="weather icon">';
      temp3 = weather.forecast[3].high + '&deg;';
      text3 = weather.forecast[3].text;

      day4 = weather.forecast[4].day;
      image4 = '<img class="weathericon" src="img/weathericons/' + weather.forecast[4].code + '.svg" alt="weather icon">';
      temp4 = weather.forecast[4].high + '&deg;';
      text4 = weather.forecast[4].text;

      day5 = weather.forecast[5].day;
      image5 = '<img class="weathericon" src="img/weathericons/' + weather.forecast[5].code + '.svg" alt="weather icon">';
      temp5 = weather.forecast[5].high + '&deg;';
      text5 = weather.forecast[5].text;

      $(".day1").html(day1);
      $(".image1").html(image1);
      $(".temp1").html(temp1);
      $(".text1").html(text1);

      $(".day2").html(day2);
      $(".image2").html(image2);
      $(".temp2").html(temp2);
      $(".text2").html(text2);

      $(".day3").html(day3);
      $(".image3").html(image3);
      $(".temp3").html(temp3);
      $(".text3").html(text3);

      $(".day4").html(day4);
      $(".image4").html(image4);
      $(".temp4").html(temp4);
      $(".text4").html(text4);

      $(".day5").html(day5);
      $(".image5").html(image5);
      $(".temp5").html(temp5);
      $(".text5").html(text5);*/

      for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++){
        day[i] = weather.forecast[i].day;
        image[i] = '<img class="weathericon" src="img/weathericons/' + weather.forecast[i].code + '.svg" alt="weather icon">';
        temp[i] = weather.forecast[i].high + '&deg;';
        text[i] = weather.forecast[i].text;      

        $(".day"+i).html(day[i]);
        $(".image"+i).html(image[i]);
        $(".temp"+i).html(temp[i]);
        $(".text"+i).html(text[i]);
      }
    },
    error: function (error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/Evexium/pen/wrQOqb

Just the for loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++){
        day[i] = weather.forecast[i].day;
        image[i] = '<img class="weathericon" src="img/weathericons/' + weather.forecast[i].code + '.svg" alt="weather icon">';
        temp[i] = weather.forecast[i].high + '&deg;';
        text[i] = weather.forecast[i].text;      

        $(".day"+i).html(day[i]);
        $(".image"+i).html(image[i]);
        $(".temp"+i).html(temp[i]);
        $(".text"+i).html(text[i]);
      }
```

I think my problem is here:

```
$(".day"+[i]).html(day[i]);
$(".image"+[i]).html(image[i]);
$(".temp"+[i]).html(temp[i]);
$(".text"+[i]).html(text[i]);
```

But I don't know how to make it work. Help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines don't look right:

```
$(".day[i]").html(day[i]);
$(".image"+[i]).html(image[i]);
```

The correct JQuery selectors should look like this:

```
$(".day"+i).html(day[i]);
$(".image"+i).html(image[i]);
```

Assuming your class are `day1`, `image1`, etc.

Comment: Yes those are my classes, for some reason I receive the error in Chrome's console: ReferenceError: day is not defined. This error is for the first day inside the forloop.

Comment: You need to define your vars with the `var` keyword.